# IOS Swift spirtekit Memory Leak delete sk scene

Tags: ios, swift, memory, sprite

I have created a game that opens up a UIViewController as a main screen then a button on the main screen opens up the Gamescene ViewController which then opens Gamescene.swift. That is the skscene of the game. When you die in the game you can go back to the main screen.

The only problem is when you go back into the game for a second time the memory doubles and then triples and so on. I believe it is opening a new skscene each time but I'm not sure how to delete the scenes or allow for just one scene to be used.

Comment: can you post how you're creating the scene ? 

You want there to be no more pointers to the child scenes, so you wanna make sure you dismiss all the child view controller for the mainscreen, so in the gameviewcontroller that isn't your main screen you can call:

self.removeFromParentViewController()

If you post a snippet of your code where you create your scene I can try taking a close look.